# How to micromanage after 25 levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

After you have a lot of levels in tiny death star, it starts to get hard to micromanage it.

Are there any known tricks that can help save time and still make decent profit & progress?

**Edit:**
If you guys could also suggest a layout order for these micromanage recommendations that will be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have time to constantly stock your shops, you can upgrade those shops with low turn-around times (and thus lower quantity of goods) to increase the production numbers of the goods. This would enable these shops to generate income for you for a wee bit longer, and you can afford to check back less frequently.

You can either spend bux to upgrade your shops (which is relatively cheap when the shops are still low levels) or you can use the Level Upgrader VIP.

Having said that, you can also use the above VIP to concentrate on upgrading the level with the highest quantity of level 3 goods (currently, that's Imperial Court, if you have all the levels). Then only build the level 3 good on this level. When the Big Spender VIP comes along, use him to buy out this level for a quick and big profit. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I have 70+ levels now (including 13 of the Imperial), and I've found that over the course of an hour per day (not constant), I can power through stocking all the 1/2 levels, and then before I go to bed I hit the level 3 exclusively.

During the day if I get a spare moment, I don't bother sending Bitizens to their requested level unless it goes to an unfilled apartment vacancy level. Otherwise, I just send them to an Imperial level. VIPs I send if they're interesting, otherwise I toss them to level 2.

I second the recommendation to level your higher-producing shops. For me, that's Rancor Pit and Imperial Court. I have level 18 on both of them, and I'm able to get well over 100K from Imperial Court 3rd item with a Big Spender, so that's cool.

Comment: explain "unfilled apartment vacancy level" please. do you get anything for sending them to imperial level except -1 min cd?

Comment: I mean that I'd only send them to their requested level if they'll move into the Death Star. Otherwise, sending them to the Imperial Level to either decrease time remaining, or just to get them off my plate if I have nothing being constructed on the lower levels.

Comment: I'd say that if your tower is still under construction, you shouldn't be spending money on making imperial stuff at all, you need that money for more levels.  But yes, once your tower is complete, and you have a few million left over, and all you are trying to do is finish imperial assignments, yeah, you will likely benefit more from shaving a few minutes off of those than getting a few hundred coin from sending them up the tower.  (I'm assuming imp assignments don't scale by tower height)

Comment: Honestly, I have enough of a commerce engine that I can create a new level about once per day if I have good stock. I make back the few thousand credits I spend on Imperial missions in a few minutes, so it doesn't really hurt. Thanks to the recent mission, I have a stockpile of items that I need to work through too, so it's not like I'm wasting money by finishing the missions.

Answer (score 1):

Build excess residential capacity.  You want to increase the chances that the elevator will take a bitizen to a level with a vacancy.

Higher skill people slightly decrease the stocking time, but more importantly, people working at their dream job double the stock at one tier, three dream-jobbers double all the stock. (Ordering times remain the same) Also, you get a Bux when you place a person in their dream job, even if you evict them right after.  So you want high bitizen turnover, to increase the odds of getting the bitizens you want, with dream jobs that you can match for the bux.  Don't let a person work at a job that's not their dream job unless there is another vacancy on their residential floor.  A skill 2 person working their dream job is better than a skill 9 person not working their dream job.

You want to use Bux to improve your elevator immediately, at least to level 4, if not 5.  A faster elevator makes the game far more pleasant to play (though it's a lot harder to make a level 5 elevator drop off a person at the desired imperial level)

Build more service levels than the others...as Han mentioned, Imperial Court is the level with the highest base amount of stock, and that's a service level.  You want that to have 3 dream-jobbers, to double the amount of tier 3 stock, you want to throw upgraders at that, to increase the stock even more, so that when you throw a Big Spender at it when the level 3 stock has just been filled, you make lots of money selling lots of tier 3 stock.

If you don't have that level, throw your upgraders at whatever level has the potential to have the most level 3 stock until you get Imperial Court.

Prior to the upgrade last week, imperial assignments gave out way more money then one had to put into them, which made them worthwhile investments.  That does not appear to be the case now, so I think you can just ignore them, unless one happens to pay out bux or VIPs.  You need the money for your new levels.

If you want to know how to organize your death star, it doesn't much matter.  I put all my residential levels at the bottom, and group the rest by type.  Part of me is tempted to reorganize by the # minutes it takes to order tier 1 stock, so that Workout Center and Mos Espa Cafe will be next to each other.

The "Find the Bitizen" events will get to be more of a pain as your tower grows...consider dressing people so that you know where they work.  If a bitizen isn't at work, they are at home.  (Rebel spies can be on any positive level, even levels under construction)